# Writing the data to the mongoDB database constantly in a efficient way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, streaming

I'm currently working on a system where the data is coming at a rapid pace, 100 data points per minute (iot data), I want to store the data in my database (mongoDB) as they come. Is there any way I can make writing to the database using a stream? Or any other way I can write the data to the database constantly as and when they arrive in my system.

Current flow of data is:-

```
aws iot core -> rules engine -> aws kinesis data streams -> nodejs application
```

My database strucuture is a 3 collection structure which aims at providing the schema flexibility to the users :-

```
Datasource collection : Id,name
Variable collection : Id, DatasourceId, name
Values collection : Id, variableId, value, timestamp (time-series collection)
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: 100 documents per minute is not much. In my application I insert up to 100'000 documents every second.

Comment: What approach do you follow? @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: The data is collected with syslog-ng and then inserted with `mongoimport`. However, syslog-ng added bulk inserts for mongo driver (not yet released). So in future releases syslog-ng should be able to insert this amount of data directly. See here, how I did it https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/3454